# Nginx in docker container to execute Perl script in other container. Buffering problem

Tags: docker, perl, nginx

I am building the web server where Nginx runs in docker container. And there are another 2 docker containers for PHP code and for Perl code (cgi).

PHP container works very good.
But not cgi container to execute Perl. It works slow for file uploads

Nginx config looks like this

```
........
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    proxy_buffering                 off;
    proxy_request_buffering         off;
    proxy_http_version              1.1;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort       on;
    client_body_timeout             180s;
    client_max_body_size            0;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size        0;
    proxy_read_timeout              300s;
    proxy_send_timeout              300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 2s;

    location ~* \.php$ {
         client_body_timeout  180s;
         client_max_body_size 0;
         fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
         include         fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
         fastcgi_send_timeout 900s;
         fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
         fastcgi_keep_conn on;
         fastcgi_socket_keepalive on;
    }
    location ~* ^/cgi-bin/.+\.cgi {
         client_body_timeout  172800s;
         client_max_body_size 0;
         gzip off;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass   cgi:9001;
         fastcgi_request_buffering off;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
         fastcgi_send_timeout 900s;

         fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
         fastcgi_keep_conn on;
         fastcgi_socket_keepalive on;
     }
```

Inside cgi container i do the following

```
cat ../nginx-build/cgi/Dockerfile 
FROM ff-base

RUN apt update &&\
    apt upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install -y spawn-fcgi fcgiwrap

EXPOSE 9001

#CMD ["/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap", "-f", "-s", "tcp:0.0.0.0:9001"]
CMD ["/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi", "-n", "-a", "0.0.0.0","-p","9001","--","/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap"]
```

My base image has the code to install perl etc. No important here.

So, **what is the problem**.

When i change the option
fastcgi_request_buffering off;
to **on**, all start to work fine with uploads to cgi container. But i need to have it off. I need my perl script reads data immediately users started to post it. I do not want to have buffering.
And in general it works. Bu very slowly. Upload with buffering takes 5 sec for 28mb file. But upload of same file without buffering takes 1m20sec.

My perl file is simplest. It only reads input and does nothing with it, only counts. I played with different size of read buffer 1kb,2,4,16 etc. No difference

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

logIt("start");

print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "\n";

logIt("Before read started");

binmode(STDIN);
my $readbuffer;
my $bytes_read=0;

while(!eof(STDIN) && $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"} > 0){
    my $toread = 65636;

        if ($bytes_read + $toread > $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"}) {
            $toread = $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"} - $bytes_read;
        }

        read(STDIN, $readbuffer, $toread);
        logIt("read ".length($readbuffer));     
    $bytes_read+=length($readbuffer);
                
    last if($bytes_read>=$ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"});
}
print "Uploaded $bytes_read bytes\n";
logIt("done file read $bytes_read bytes");

sub logIt{
    my $s=shift;

        my $fname = "/logfile.txt";

        if(open LOGFF, ">> $fname"){
            print LOGFF "[".scalar(localtime)."] ".$$.": $s\n";
                close LOGFF;
        }
}
```

Results of this script shows that data appear in a read buffer regularly but read is slow. Like 5-6 reads per second.

So, my problem is maybe inside /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap or in spawn-fcgi related to how they read data transferred from nginx container (nginx just sends data because no buffering).

**Why could this be too slow?**

Comment: Buffering problems are usually on the *writer*'s side (`/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap`). You could try using `sysread` (a simple wrapper around `read(2)`) instead of `read`, but I can't think of anything else that might help on the *reader*'s side.

Comment: Whether you use `read` or `sysread`, I think you want `length($kueri)` as a fourth argument. (Unrelated to the question.)

Comment: i am not sure i need 4-th argument for read. 3-rd argument is a number of bytes to read. it is now 16kb and can be set to less if there is less data in the buffer.

Comment: If you want the whole input to end up in `$kueri`, you need the 4th arg. Otherwise, you are overwriting previous reads instead of appending.

Comment: I do not need a response. This script is just for testing. I do not accumulate a response somewhere, i only increase counter to know how much bytes i received and how much time was spent to read full input.
Offset is not needed because i read from STDIN and seek works here after every read.

Comment: sysread works same slow as read. The only difference is that read returns exact number of bytes (16kb) each time, but sysread returns different number of bytes. I see 4096, 12288, 8192, 16384. I am not sure this means something

Comment: That is expected. `read` will perform multiple reads of a fixed size (chosen when `perl` is built, 8 KiB by default these days) until the requested amount is obtained (buffering the rest). `sysread` is a thin wrapper around `read(2)`, which 1) returns immediately when data is available, or 2) returns immediately as soon as data arrives. (At least, that's the behaviour on Linux.) /// Anyway, as far as I'm concerned, this confirms the problem isn't in the CGI script you posted, but in `/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap` or higher up the chain.

Comment: Wait, there's no reason for `fcgiwrap` to send some random amount of data that's smaller than the amount available.  That makes absolutely no sense. That means the data is actually received by `fcgiwrap` slowly like that.

Comment: So, can it be nginx resends data to fcgiwrap too slowly? When buffering is enabled, my script receives data all immidiately. So, nginx sends it fast and fcgireads and resends to my script also fast.

Comment: I mean, that makes just as little sense, and for the same reason. Why would nginx just send a small random-sized portion of what it has waiting?